# How to access variables declared in an element from a view

Tags: php, cakephp

Let's say I have a a view and an element:

```
myElement{
    $aVar = 'abc';
}


myView{
    <?php echo $this->element('myElement'); ?>
    <?php echo $aVar; ?>  (outputs: abc)
}
```

After I render the element in the view, how can I access the variable declared in that element from my view?  When I try this, the variable is undefined.

Comment: Why do you have a class myView that opens a bracket and then have some PHP open tag in there? This code is technically incorrect and can't work. Please provide the real code...

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
// controller
$this->set('aVar', 'aValue');

// view or layout
echo $this->element('myElement', array('someVar'=>$aVar));

// myElement
echo $someVar; // outputs 'aValue' in 'myElement'
```

Comment: And setting it from the controller makes it available as "aVar" in the element right away. the "someVar" cast is additional, then. Just to add my five cents here.

Comment: Yes, this does work. However, the question is concerning outputting the value outside of the element, in the view.  If the element changed the value, how can I see it in the view?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CakePHP 1.3 the API for this is:

```
$this->set('dog', 'Sammy');
$this->getVar('dog'); // Sammy
```

Ref: https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html#getvar